# Issue with alternating colors row table with selectable rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue with a generated table that has alternating rows and the rows are selectable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("tr").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
  })
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}
th {
  font: bold 11px"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #F2EDEB;
  border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
  background: #522D25 url(images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
}
tr {
  background: #fff;
  color: #261F1D;
}
tr:hover,
tr.alt:hover {
  color: #261F1D;
  background-color: #E5C37E;
}
.highlighted {
  color: #261F1D;
  background-color: #E5C37E;
}
tr.alt {
  background: #F5FAFA;
  color: #B4AA9D;
}
td {
  border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="fooBar" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is this: If I put the alternating colors, the select row table function does not work, if I remove it ... it works again. Any Ideas?

I need to dynamically create a table with alternating rows that are selectable. I want to be able to use something very basic, don't need all functionality of datatables library.

Answer (score 2):

You'll just need to reorganize the rules slightly. In your original demo the pseudo selector `tr:nth-child(odd)` or `tr:nth-child(even)` has higher specificity than `.highlighted`. All you have to do is add the same `tr` selector to `.highlighted` it becomes to `tr.highlighted`, and move it below the pseudo selectors, as last loaded rules get applied for equal specificity selectors.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
tr.highlighted {
  color: #261F1D;
  background-color: #E5C37E;
}
tr:hover {
  color: #261F1D;
  background-color: #E5C37E;
}
```

See the updated demo below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("tr").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("highlighted");
  })
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}
tr {
  background: #fff;
  color: #261F1D;
}
th {
  font: bold 11px"Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #F2EDEB;
  border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-top: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
  background: #522D25 url(images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
}
td {
  border-right: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C1DAD7;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 12px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
tr.highlighted {
  color: #261F1D;
  background-color: #E5C37E;
}
tr:hover {
  color: #261F1D;
  background-color: #E5C37E;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="fooBar" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="">
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
    <td>Text</td>
    <td>image</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This tool is very useful - https://specificity.keegan.st/ to understand CSS specificity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `!important` on hover and highlighted styles, so that those styles will override the default styles.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1x1farow/

Comment: Thank you so much. It works ... I hope I won't encounter any further issues with !important, but for now I'll be able to continue my work.

Comment: If you don't want to have any conflicts then use the id before the tr like this `#foobar tr:hover` instead of `tr:hover`, so that the style only applies to tr inside a fooBar table. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1x1farow/1/. Please accept the answer, if it helps. :)

Comment: !important can become a pain, you should  try to avoid it as much as possible ;)